# zsh: my shell script that works well on bash does NOT work on zsh

Tags: bash, pipe, zsh, incompatibility

```
alias tmutil-rmla='unsetopt multios; echo "tmutil listlocalsnapshots /|sudo tm_removeAllLocalSnapshots" 1>&2; tmutil listlocalsnapshots /|sudo tm_removeAllLocalSnapshots'
```

And tm_removeAllLocalSnapshots is an execution file made from the Swift compiler on macOS.
(I've made it)

The alias does work well on Bash but ended up 'suspended` on zsh as the followings:

```
% tmutil-rmla  
tmutil listlocalsnapshots /|sudo tm_removeAllLocalSnapshots
zsh: done                    tmutil listlocalsnapshots / | 
zsh: suspended (tty output)  sudo tm_removeAllLocalSnapshots
```

Would you enlighten me about this?

Comment: I only get that if I add `&`, either at the end of the command (`tmutil-rmla &`) or at the end of the end of the definition of the alias.

Comment: What is `unsetopt`?

Comment: @Barmar It's a `zsh` thing. BTW, this alias does *not* work as is in bash, because `unsetopt` (and `multios`) is a `zsh` thing. And it doesn't appear to have anything to do with the rest of the alias.

Comment: In general if you're having trouble with an alias, try rewriting it as a function.

Comment: @SungwookKim : It bash, it will produce an error message: _bash: unsetopt: command not found_ , so this is not exactly what I would call "is working on bash". On zsh, you turn off _multios_ (why?), and in bash, you don't. This might account for the different in outcome.

Comment: @SungwookKim : Also, what is `tm_removeAllLocalSnapshots`? Is this a standard command for time machine? Because I can not google it.

Comment: Even if you *aren't* having trouble with an alias, it may be simpler to rewrite it as a function anyway.

Comment: tm_removeAllLocalSnapshots is the execution file that I've programmed in Swift language.  And `unsetopt multios` is for negating the effect of the multios feature of zsh.  I'm acquainted with bash but not with zsh.  Thus I had such a problem with zsh.  The alias works upon bash but not upon zsh.

Comment: `Swift` itself can be used as a script language as well. That's why I use Swift in place of shell script.

Comment: The main purpose of the alias is removing all or parts of local snapshots of Time machine backups which is usually automated.

Comment: The alias used to be suspended on zsh, while I had no such a problem on bash before.  Even if I do the following to disdown the jobs, it is of no avail. $ disown %1

Comment: It sounds like you may have part of an old definition still in effect. What does `whence -v tmutil-rmla` print?

Comment: That produces "tmutil-rmla is an alias for unsetopt multios; echo "tmutil listlocalsnapshots /|sudo tm_removeAllLocalSnapshots" 1>&2; tmutil listlocalsnapshots /|sudo tm_removeAllLocalSnapshots"

Answer (score 0):

Here is the command of my finding to solve this:
$ setopt nohup

And then the script I'd written for bash works as charm.

It was a simple solution but I had to walk through zsh manual page by page, taking 2 days.  I'm new to zsh that it wasn't easy to understand it fully in 2 day period of time.

the default bash script had hung up without the command: zsh has different settings.  Thus we need to be careful what kinds of settings are assumed when we are switching to another shell.